# dreamspark visual studio 2013 RC license?

Tags: visual-studio, dreamspark

this is the first time that I downloaded anything from dreamspark, and I'm pretty confused of how to set up the license.

I'm a student of university of Toronto, so after I downloaded the visual studio 2013, it says "license expires in 14 days", I tried to click the "check for an updated license" and it asked me to signed in. However, I wasn't able to sign in with my UofT email account, I tried to sign in with my personal email account, and somehow it worked and the license extended to 116 days.

But I should have a license until I graduate(2015), and I"m not sure how to set this up. Would anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: What is an "UofT email account"?

Comment: Oh now I get it. "University of Toronto"?

Answer (score 1):

The final version's been released on dreamspark, and you can now download it. If you haven't installed the full version, you should uninstall all products related to Visual Studio 2013, and install the newest version. If you have already done that and you have a trial of the current version of Visual Studio 2013 installed, you can simply click 'Get Key' on the dreamspark page, and copy it. Then, in Visual Studio, click Help, About, and on the bottom right change your key. Paste your dreamspark key in and you should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait until the RTM (Ready To Manufacture) version is available in Dreamspark. (Around October 18)
It will come with a product key that unlocks all features without time limitation.
Unfortunately you'll probably have to download the RTM version again.

As far as I know the RC version from Dreamspark is the same that anyone can download for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads#d-2013-editions). It's not meant for productive work, just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Microsoft Visual Studios 2013 RC is just a trial and RC stands for Release Candidate, just to let the people try it before they purchase it on the launch day. When it has been official launched I think you will have to download it again but not the RC the full Visual Studios Professional 2013. And if you are a student you wont have to worry about any serial as the full professional serial should be embedded inside the installation file like all the other visual studios if your downloading it from dream spark that is.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the free Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition!

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to say that this problem is fixed.  The newest DreamSpark version of Visual studio comes with a license key (separate buttone next to the download button on the Dreamspark page)  Make sure you KEEP THIS PRODUCT KEY!!!  In about 30 days your "trial" license will expire.  This is because during installation, VS never asked for the product key.  Now you have a "Product License" link to click on and it display the textbox to enter the product key and viola!  VS2013 is working once again, this time for as long as you want to use it to develop and learn.

Remember, the community version (not the dreamspark version) is also a full version of VS2013 professional.  HOWEVER, you cannot use it in a business setting unless teaching others how to use it or creating open source programs.